# Unable to add punctuation without entering math mode in affiliation revtex4-2

Tags: revtex, affiliation

I'm am stumped. I have an article that starts with

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,aps,prd,amsmath,showpacs,floatfix,reprint,eprint]{revtex4-2} % chktex 8
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}   % chktex 8
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{breqn}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\title{Relativistic Langevin Equation derived from a particle-bath Lagrangian}

\author{Aleksandr \surname{Petrosyan}}
\email{ap886@cantab.cam.ac.uk}
\affiliation{Cavendish Laboratory University of Cambridge JJ Thomson Avenue CB3 0HE Cambridge U.K.}
```

This compiles fine.

If I add a comma, e.g. like this:

```
\affiliation{Cavendish Laboratory, University of Cambridge JJ Thomson Avenue CB3 0HE Cambridge U.K.}
```

LaTeX starts thinking that it's in math mode after the comma: the `University of cambridge` has all the spaces removed, and there's an error, in `\maketitle`. It finds one dollar, but not the other. For reference, I don't even have `$` to delineate equations (like all good LaTeX-ites I use `\(` and `\)`.

None of the examples of the American Physical Society help, because they never contain a comma.

My questions are

1. How do I insert a comma? even a tacky solution will do as long as it doesn't mess up the formatting.
2. Whom do I contact to mention this bug. I'm used to GitHub issues, but I'm considerably less versed in how LaTeX development is handled.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Affiliations appear in unspaced italics, possible math mode triggered by breqn package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547545/134144) and [error occurs when comma separated affiliation in revtex4-1 if breqn is loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168382/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Oh, good catch. That's definitely it.

Comment: @campa: Without you identifying `breqn` as the culprit here, I woulnd't have found the two related questions that easily.

Comment: I added the proposed code in the now deleted answer to the thread I marked as duplicate. Take your pick for the workaround you prefer, but the real answer is “don't use `breqn`”.